# Decision tree split vs importance

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, party

I recently created a decision tree model in R using the Party package (Conditional Inference Tree, ctree model).

I generated a visual representation of the decision tree, to see the splits and levels.

I also computed the variables importance using the Caret package.

```
fit.ctree <- train(formula, data=dat,method='ctree')
ctreeVarImp = varImp(fit.ctree)
```

I was under the impression that the order of the splits in the tree was related to the variable importance. i.e. the variable at the first split is the most important and so on. When I reviewed the importance of each variable it did not match up to the order of the splits.

Is it possible that the ctree model generated directly using Party is not the same as the one using Caret?

Is the order of importance of the variables in decision trees related to the order of the splits?

Comment: `ctreeVarImp$model` will tell you the method applied using `train()`. You can also simply print `ctreeVarImp`.

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with the `ctree`, but in `rpart` or CART, the variable importance is calculated in much more complicated way than the order of the split.

A detailed information can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf), page 11

> A variable may appear in the tree many times, either as a primary or a surrogate
>   variable. An overall measure of variable importance is the sum of the goodness of split
>   measures for each split for which it was the primary variable, plus goodness * (adjusted
>   agreement) for all splits in which it was a surrogate. In the printout these are scaled to sum
>   to 100 and the rounded values are shown, omitting any variable whose proportion is less
>   than 1%. Imagine two variables which were essentially duplicates of each other; if we did
>   not count surrogates they would split the importance with neither showing up as strongly
>   as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional comments, complementing the answer by @hxd1011.

- The CTree fitted by `ctree()` in `party` (or preferably the successor implementation `partykit`) uses a pre-pruning strategy based on the significance level 5%. The `caret` implementation treats the significance level not as fixed but as a tuning parameter (see https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html). In short: The trees can be different.
- Splitting order is a poor proxy for variable importance measures. It is not unrelated but it is certainly not the same. For the variable importance measures employed by `caret` see https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html